# Braintree Unsuccessful credit card verification is not working for my code

Tags: php, laravel-5, braintree

I am trying to test braintree single payment. All works fine and the code makes a transactions which I can see in the sandbox and also from response code.

But the problem is when I try to use one their 'Unsuccessful credit card numbers' it still process the transactions and gives me success as a response.

Here is the code I am using for making transaction.

```
$result = \Braintree\Transaction::sale([
        'amount' => $amount,
        'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
        'options' => [
            'submitForSettlement' => true
         ]
      ]);
```

This code never gives error unsuccessful credit card verification number.
I tried to use `verifyCard=true` in the options array and gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

For you to have an unsuccessful credit card verification, it has to happen during a `PaymentMethod::Create()` call as `:verify_card => true` can't be passed in a `Transaction.sale()` call. Therefore any [testing cards in this section](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#unsuccessful-credit-card-verification), will only fail during the attempt to make a payment method with the verify parameter used, not during a transaction. If you want to only make a transaction and have it fail, try using a different amount that can trigger different failures as documented here: [test amounts](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#test-amounts)

Comment: I see this in the docs, but why? Why make it necessary to fail one off payments differently to card verifications?